# How to centre text over image in horizontal navigation menu?

Tags: html, css

FIXED: I just needed to apply "float:left" to the "li" element rather than the imgs. Thanks!

I have a horizontal navigation menu and I am struggling to get it to work in all browsers. I have created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yTACT/

It works great in Chrome, Safari and Opera. However in Firefox and Internet Explorer the text isn't properly centred over each button. Instead the text starts on the second button and overflows to the right.

Can anyone work out a way to fix it?

HTML

```
<div id="nav">

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.htm"><span>HOME</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/home-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Home Button" title="Home" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="how-use-services.htm"><span>HOW TO USE OUR SERVICES</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/how-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. How To Use Our Services Button" title="How To Use Our Services" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="playstation-repair.htm"><span>PLAYSTATION REPAIR</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/playstation-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Playstation Repair Button" title="Playstation Repair" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="xbox-repair.htm"><span>XBOX REPAIR</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/xbox-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Xbox Repair Button" title="Xbox Repair" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="wii-repair.htm"><span>WII REPAIR</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/wii-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Wii Repair Button" title="Wii Repair" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="customer-reviews.htm"><span>CUSTOMER REVIEWS</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/reviews-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Customer Reviews Button" title="Customer Reviews" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="location-map.htm"><span>LOCATION AND MAP</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/map-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Location And Map Button" title="Location and Map" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm"><span>CONTACT US</span><img src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/contact-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Contact Us Button" title="Contact Us" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul, ol, dl {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}

#nav {
position:relative;
width:960px;
height:115px;
margin-bottom:10px;
background-image: url(http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/nav-bg.png);
}

#nav li a span {  
position:absolute;
width: 120px; 
top: 70px; 
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#fff;
}

#nav li a img {
float:left;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
}


#nav li a:hover img {
opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: why u dont use after ,before in css ?

Comment: Sorry to waste your time but it's all sorted now. I just needed to apply "float:left" on the "li" element rather than the imgs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On `#nav li{ position: relative; }` and on `li img{ left: 0;}`

Here's the code. http://jsfiddle.net/yTACT/8/

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. It centres the text for all the buttons on the first button. I have found a solution though. Check OP if you're interested. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle linke I was in a hurry and wrote some bad things there :) anyway I'm glad you fixed it :)